# How to convert android MediaRecorder output to MP3 file

Tags: android, mediarecorder

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder#java

In this example from the link above (the first Sample Code in the link), they use 3gp. I was wondering how you could turn this to mp3. Do I just change it the ending to ".mp3"?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // Record to the external cache directory for visibility
    fileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    fileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 
    REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    recordButton = new RecordButton(this);
    ll.addView(recordButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    0));
    playButton = new PlayButton(this);
    ll.addView(playButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    0));
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

**+ Can anyone please explain where that file being saved? Where can I look for the saved audio file?**

Comment: There's nothing in this code about recording audio.  It simply sets up a layout and a string variable.

Comment: in the link there is @AleksG

Comment: Don't rely on external links. They are here today, gone tomorrow. Put the relevant info into the question directly.

Comment: @AleksG it's the official android website...

Comment: @AleksG problem resolved! Turns out you can't save the audio in an MP3 file...